# image upload to server in windows phone8 app

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, upload, server

I want to upload an image from the gallery or live pic (camera capture task) with some params; x = "some string", y = "some string", z = "some integer" and uploadimage = name of file tag in form.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: where do you want to upload the image..? do you have any webService ready and you just want a working implementation of WebService call to upload image file to your server..? Make your question more clear..

Answer (score 0):

Uploading image for WP8 was pain to setup. Many of the examples I follow was outdated and this took me days to research and finally got one to work. There are a few ways to upload:

1) Convert the image to a string and then you can send the image converted string via HTTP request. I've used this approach for Android, but haven't tried it for WP.
2) Upload the image via FTP and the text data via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices to upload any `File` to server.

- Convert file into `Stream` - recommend way
- Convert file into `ByteArray`
- Convert file into `String`

After that you can use [`HttpClient` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) make a `POST request` to server. Here is the code to demonstrate FileUpload by converting it into Stream.

**Code:**

```
    public async void methodToUploadFile()
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("Assets/MyImage.png");
        // var fileBytes = await GetBytesAsync(file);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        // give the server URI here
        Uri requestUri = new Uri("Full Server URI", UriKind.Absolute);

        MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formdata.Add(new StringContent("some string"), "x");
        formdata.Add(new StringContent("some string"), "y");
        formdata.Add(new StringContent("some integer"), "z");

        formdata.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()), "file", "MyImage.png");
        // formdata.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes), "file", "MyImage.png");

        // Make a POST request here
        var res = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, formdata);
    }
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Thanks Keval. Your code helped me a lot. With few modifications i did it.

Comment: I'll try to post my codes which will help others too.